# Update dlls inside a web role

Tags: azure

I have just deployed an app to windows azure staging but however I need to some quick changes in order for me to test out my app...I have manually tried copying the dll across, restarted iis, but still the changes are not being reflected in the azure virtual machine.

What else do I need to do in order for my changes to be reflected by azure?

I am fully aware that I need to create a package and deploy it, but I just want to try out a few things, as deployment takes at least 15 min each time....

Comment: You can do an in-place upgrade which takes something like 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable and use Web Deploy.  Check the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683672.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well the Azure IIS deployment is similar to any IIS deployment, so changes should take place immendiately.
The things you should check it

- Are there multiple instances? In which case you need to update all.
- Are you deploying your dlls in the right folder? One way to confirm this is to open IIS management console (inetmgr) on the machine and do a `Explore` on the Application root.

Web Deploy would work but, requires instance count to be 1 and the setting has to be enabled before package is u'poaded.